# OKI MB441 driver is not installing

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-8.1, scanner

After some perturbations with this driver, I am unable to install it anymore.

Now, after driver install, it is not appear in Device Manager. Also, neither application can see scanner and acquire data from it.

The only place where driver appears -- is `Programs and Features` list.

**UPDATE**

Driver was working first time I installed it.

Comment: Please fill in the backstory this question seems like a reply to something this driver is labeled as a windows 8.1 driver correct?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your question. I was trying to fix unrelated question with scanner, and was installing both dirver from accompanying CD and latest driver from the web. Then I was removing these drivets, trying to wipe them out and install again. No messages about Windows version was met.

Comment: He's asking if the driver you used was specifically marked as Windows 8.1 compatible.

Comment: CD ROM is marked, yes, Windows 8 compatible. Separatedly downloaded driver also marked as windows 8 compatible.

Comment: Windows 8 or windows 8.1 there is a difference

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct driver - I wonder if you are trying to use a 32 bit driver with a 64 bit OS ?

Comment: I tried everything. 32 bit causes error when trying to install.